# Kendo UI TreeView difference between dataTextField and model.fields.text.from

Tags: javascript, model, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a [HierarchicalDataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/hierarchicaldatasource/overview) where the text of the node is supplied by the `title` field. TreeView expects that field to be `text`. There are two ways of making that mapping:

1. passing [`dataTextField`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#configuration-dataTextField)`: 'title'` to the `treeview` constructor
2. passing `schema.model:`[`fields.text.from`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#fields), which "Specifies the field of the original record which value to be used for population of the Model field." i.e. `schema: { model: { fields: { text: { from: 'title' } },... }`

[Barring the grammatical mistakes](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-docs/pull/599) in the documentation for `options.fields`, which method should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dataTextField` option enables referring to the properties of the node by their original names in the data, in this case `title`:

```
var myHDS = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            var node = myHDS.get(options.data.id);
            // node.title is accessible here
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            hasChildren: 'children'
        }
    }
});

$("#tree-container").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: myHDS,
    dataTextField: 'title'
})
```

Setting `schema.model.fields.text.from` to `title` will require you to refer to the `title` property of the node as `node.text`:

```
var myHDS = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            var node = myHDS.get(options.data.id);
            // node.title is accessible here
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                text: {
                    from: 'title'
                }
            },
            id: 'id',
            hasChildren: 'children'
        }
    }
});

$("#tree-container").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: myHDS
})
```